# Replace or Update Base Template of a Template

Tags: powershell-extensions, templates

I am trying to remove a base template if found and add a different base template if not found. In the code below the standard template is never found even though I know its there. Is it because I'm trying to find the template on a template? Should I use descendants somehow? I've commented the remove and add for now...

```
$baseL = Get-Item -Path "master:\sitecore\Templates\Toro\Foundation\Language\_Language Fallback";
$baseS = Get-Item -Path "master:\sitecore\templates\System\Templates\Standard template";

cd master:\Templates\Toro\Feature\;

Get-ChildItem -recurse | ForEach-Object {

    if ($_.TemplateName -eq 'Template') {

        # Get the direct template for the item, then check to see if it has a certain base template based on the template's ID
        $hasSTemplate = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($_).InheritsFrom($baseS.ID);

        # Remove Standard Template
        if ($hasSTemplate) {
            echo "Yep, it has that template."
            #Remove-BaseTemplate -Path "master:/sitecore/content/User Defined/Page" -TemplateItem @($baseS)
        }

         # Get the direct template for the item, then check to see if it has a certain base template based on the template's ID
        $hasLTemplate = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($_).InheritsFrom($baseL.ID);

        # Add Language Template
        if ($hasLTemplate –eq $FALSE) {
            echo "Yep, it does not have that template."
            #Add-BaseTemplate -Path "master:/sitecore/content/User Defined/Page" -TemplateItem @($baseL)
        }

        Write-Host $_.FullPath
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you are headed in the right direction when it comes to adding and removing base templates. You can use this command to help you determine when items are referring to a given template.

```powershell
# Id references the Standard Template
Get-Item -Path "master:{1930BBEB-7805-471A-A3BE-4858AC7CF696}" | Get-ItemReferrer
```

[image: Referencing Standard Template]

If one of your user defined templates inherits from the specified template you will know it through the above query.

Is the Standard Template causing an issue with your templates?

Comment: No - I just need to replace it with the language fallback template which intern inherits from the standard.